# How does the “suddenness” of applying a force affects tension?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

Basically this question below. I can’t seem to comprehend the reasoning depicted in the solutions manual. I can’t see the logic behind that a sudden force will cause the bottom string to tear first, but a slow force will cause the upper string. Please help me understand this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is important to see that the transmition of force is not instant (imagine a force that provokes oscillations in a rope for example, the perturbation do not arrive instantly at the other end of the rope). In this exercise, the idea of suddennes is related to applying a strong pull quickly (strong enough to tear the string), in a way that when the perturbation arrives the stone it will apply an equally strong reaction force in the lower string, causing it to break before the perturbation arrives at the upper string and the ceiling.

Now, if the force applied were to slowly become stronger, the disturbance would have enough time to arrive the upper string + ceiling, because the lower string did not tear apart. And, in this situation, the upper string endures the tension and the weight of the stone in order to remain still, such that it results in a force bigger than the pull alone (which is the force that would be responsible for breaking the lower string).

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you for your answer!!

Comment: Your welcome, I hope it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the strings are Hookean (at least until one of the strings breaks), the tension in the bottom string is proportional to the displacement from zero tension in the bottom string, while to tension in the top string is proportional to the displacement from zero tension in the top string.

In the case of a very slowly increasing force on the lower string, it helps to look first at a constant force in the lower string with both strings still intact. The tension in the upper string will be equal to the tension in the bottom string plus the weight of the rock. The tension in the upper string is always greater than the tension on the lower string in the case of a constant force.

If the force on the lower string is increased by a tiny bit, the rock will move downward a tiny bit until the tension in the upper string increases to match the tension in the bottom string plus the weight of the rock. Increasing the tension in the lower string slowly enough will ensure that the tension in the upper string is always greater than the tension on the lower string. The upper string is the first to snap in the case of a slowly increasing tension in the bottom string.

Suppose instead that the tension in the bottom string is suddenly increased  by pulling down on the bottom string quickly. Even though the downward force on the rock has increased by a lot, the rock will not have moved much because because the period of application is small. The tension in the bottom string becomes greater than the tension in the top string given a fast enough downward pull on the bottom string. It's the bottom string that snaps in this case.

Comment: A nice horizontal analog is the parlor trick of pulling a tablecloth off a table with dishes and glasses atop the table cloth. Do this slowly and the dishes and glasses will move with the table cloth and go crashing onto the floor. Do it quickly enough and the dishes and glasses stay more or less in place.